# mod_rewrite Multiple Variables and Subfolders

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

On my site I have multiple URLs like this:

Main Page:

```
mysite.com
mysite.com/?content=about
mysite.com/?content=posts&page=2
```

Subfolders:

```
mysite.com/subsite/
mysite.com/subsite/?content=about
mysite.com/subsite2/?content=posts&page=2
```

I'd like to make clean these up to be:

```
mysite.com/about/
mysite.com/posts/2

mysite.com/subsite/about/
mysite.com/subsite/posts/2
```

Now, I've been able to use mod_rewrite for one variable, and some other simple things, but I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this. When I use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /?content=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

It recognizes the sections of the URL as variables, but it also sees the subsite as a variable, and attempts to plug in 'subsite' for 'content'.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by putting another `.htaccess` file in the `subsite` folder.

The root `.htaccess` has:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

---

In the subsite `.htaccess` I have: (same as root .htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ?a=b&content=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

If you do not need to alter the subdirectory's url, add only `RewriteEngine On` to the subsite's `.htaccess`. This basically overrides the root `.htaccess` rewrite rules, and loads the page from the subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

You could tweak you existing rule to allow for an OPTIONAL **subsite/** or **subsite2/** prefix e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(subsite/|subsite2/)?([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/$   /$1?content=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Or just add a rule to handle the subsites before the existing rule e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(subsite/|subsite2/)([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ /$1?content=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /?content=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try that out soon. So is there no need for a second htaccess file in the 'subsite' and 'subsite2' folders?